# Custom Kivy Widget yields only black screen

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, kivy

I am trying to create a custom kivy widget, but when I render it in my test app, a blank screen shows up.  I've tried tracing code calls and it looks like all of the initialization and drawing methods are being called (I have included the terminal output from the print statements below the widget code.  I am also including my test app, but this is very simple and is the same shell I've used for several working apps I've already created).  My application main loop begins, but nothing is displayed.  Why am I not seeing my widget?

[Edit]So I've gotten the NodeEnd objects to render with some major structural changes, bringing a lot of the code into .kv language.  I'm replacing the code on the post with the newer version.  Unfortunately, the label between them is still not rendering

nodewidget.kv

```
#: kivy 1.9.0

<NodeEnd>
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.color[0], self.color[1], self.color[2], self.color[3]
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.center
            size: self.width / 2, self.height / 2
            angle_start: self.degree_range[0]
            angle_end: self.degree_range[1]

<NodeWidget>
    left: left
    body: body
    right: right
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        NodeEnd:
            id: left
            degree_range: 180, 360
            on_pressed: self.PressedLeft(self, args[0])
            on_moved: self.MovedLeft(self, args[0])
            on_released: self.ReleasedLeft(self, args[0])
            on_color: self.LeftSwitch(self, args[0])
        NodeBody:
            id: body
            text: self.title
            on_pressed: self.PressedBody(self, args[0])
            on_moved: self.MovedBody(self, args[0])
            on_released: self.ReleasedBody(self, args[0])
            on_pressed_flag: self.BodySwitch(self, args[0])
        NodeEnd:
            id: right
            degree_range: 0, 180
            on_pressed: self.PressedRight(self, args[0])
            on_moved: self.MovedRight(self, args[0])
            on_released: self.ReleasedRight(self, args[0])
            on_color: self.RightSwitch(self, args[0])
```

NodeWidget3.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('nodewidget.kv')

class NodeWidget(GridLayout):

    title = StringProperty('')
    pressed_body = ListProperty([0, 0])
    released_body = ListProperty([0, 0])
    moved_body = ListProperty([0, 0])
    switch_body = BooleanProperty(False)
    pressed_left = ListProperty([0, 0])
    released_left = ListProperty([0, 0])
    moved_left = ListProperty([0, 0])
    switch_left = BooleanProperty(False)
    pressed_right = ListProperty([0, 0])
    released_right = ListProperty([0, 0])
    moved_right = ListProperty([0, 0])
    switch_right = BooleanProperty(False)

    left = ObjectProperty(None)
    body = ObjectProperty(None)
    right = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NodeWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def PressedBody(self, *args):
        self.pressed_body = args
    def MovedBody(self, *args):
        self.moved_body = args
    def ReleasedBody(self, *args):
        self.released_body = args
    def BodySwitch(self, *args):
        pass
    def PressedLeft(self, *args):
        self.pressed_left = args
    def MovedLeft(self, *args):
        self.moved_left = args
    def ReleasedLeft(self, *args):
        self.released_left = args
    def LeftSwitch(self, *args):
        pass
    def PressedRight(self, *args):
        self.pressed_right = args
    def MovedRight(self, *args):
        self.moved_right = args
    def ReleasedRight(self, *args):
        self.released_right = args
    def RightSwitch(self, *args):
        pass

class NodeBody(Label):

#on_color is triggered on down or up on the button and move off or on the button
#it will return the initial values when the button is not pressed
#when the button is pressed, this will return True
    pressed_flag = BooleanProperty(False)

#on_pressed is triggered when the button is initially hit
    pressed = ListProperty([0, 0])

#on_released is triggered when the button is released
    released = ListProperty([0, 0])

#on_moved is triggered when the touch is moved and the touch is not taken outside the button
    moved = ListProperty([0, 0])

    title = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NodeBody, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.pressed = touch.pos
            self.pressed_flag = True
            return touch
        return super(NodeBody, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.moved = touch.pos
            self.pressed_flag = True
            return touch
        self.pressed_flag = False
        return super(NodeBody, self).on_touch_move(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.released = touch.pos
            self.pressed_flag = False
            return touch
        return super(NodeBody, self).on_touch_up(touch)

class NodeEnd(Widget):

#on_color is triggered on down or up on the button and move off the button
#it will return the initial values when the button is not pressed
#when the button is pressed, this will return [0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 1]
#Not meant to be updated via code, only generate events
    color = ListProperty([0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8])

#[90, 270] for left
#[270, 90] for right
    degree_range = ListProperty([0, 0])

#on_pressed is triggered when the button is initially hit
    pressed = ListProperty([0, 0])

#on_released is triggered when the button is released
    released = ListProperty([0, 0])

#on_moved is triggered when the button is moved and the touch is not taken outside the button
    moved = ListProperty([0, 0])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NodeEnd, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.pressed = touch.pos
            self.color = [0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 1]
            return touch
        return super(NodeEnd, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.moved = touch.pos
            self.color = [0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 1]
            return touch
        self.color = [0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8]
        self.released = touch.pos
        return super(NodeEnd, self).on_touch_move(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.released = touch.pos
            self.color = [0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8]
            return touch
        return super(NodeEnd, self).on_touch_up(touch)
```

The test app:

nodeeditor.kv

```
#kivy 1.9.0

<NodeEditorWidget>:
    GridLayout:
        size: root.size
        cols: 3
        NodeWidget:
            title: 'Test 1'
            on_pressed_body: app.SelectNode(self, args[0])
            on_moved_body: app.MoveNode(self, args[0])
            on_released_body: app.DeselectNode(self, args[0])
            on_pressed_left: app.SelectLeft(self, args[0])
            on_moved_left: app.MoveLeft(self, args[0])
            on_released_left: app.DeselectLeft(self, args[0])
            on_pressed_right: app.SelectRight(self, args[0])
            on_moved_right: app.MoveRight(self, args[0])
            on_released_right: app.DeselectRight(self, args[0])
```

NodeTest.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from NodeWidget3 import NodeWidget

Builder.load_file('nodeeditor.kv')

class NodeEditorWidget(Widget):
    pass

class NodeEditorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return NodeEditorWidget()
        print('Node Editor initialized')

    def SelectNode(self, *args):
        pass

    def MoveNode(self, *args):
        pass

    def DeselectNode(self, *args):
        pass

    def SelectLeft(self, *args):
        pass

    def MoveLeft(self, *args):
        pass

    def DeselectLeft(self, *args):
        pass

    def SelectRight(self, *args):
        pass

    def MoveRight(self, *args):
        pass

    def DeselectRight(self, *args):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NodeEditorApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Kivy and Python so i hope this helps. When declaring and adding the widgets to your layout try adding 'self' at the beginning. Also in your original app i noticed you imported App but i don't see an App class.
In your test I added self to all the things and I also added a button. The button appeared in the window but the rest was black. So I have to ask when you are adding your widgets did you pick a color for them? It may be they are appearing black by default or/and might be the self thing. Hope this helps.

Comment: You're on the right track regarding the self declaration, I found some more information at the link below which was the inspiration for the last edit: http://inclem.net/2014/10/10/kivy/kivy_update_instructions/